# django-registration with paypal integration

Tags: django, paypal, activation, django-registration

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate django-registration with django-paypal.  Being a Django n00b, I'm trying to figure out how to implement a flow like this:

1. User signs up using django-registation with 'active' flag set to 0
2. After registering, send user to PayPal for a subscription
3. When they come back from PayPal successfully, I want to set 'active' to 1

I've been looking at the django-registration documentation and don't quite understand how to use different backends or implement a flow the way I want.

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.  django-paypal won't be a problem for me as I've done PayPal integration before (in PHP for a self-published book about CakePHP).

Comment: I just started using Django-PayPal... I don't know how subscriptions work, but I imagine they'd work much the same way as IPN... it should send a post-back to your site, and then Django-PayPal should send you  a signal... inside that signal you just activate the user.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how you tell django-registration to NOT send the activation email but instead send them to the paypal page for a subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have registration not send an email you pass `send_email=False` to the `RegistrationManager.create_inactive_user` call in your view to register a user.  After you create the user, you probably want to create a landing page with the paypal buttons for payment.  Instruct the user to click a payment button to pay.  Generally I send the `user.id` in the `custom` field for the payment button.

Then, in `django-paypal`, use the IPN signal handlers to activate the user based on the `user.id` in the `custom` field of the IPN query.  You might want to send a modified registration email at this point, welcoming the user to your site and telling them you have received payment and have activated their account, but those are details for you to define.